# SOAPUI Data Driven

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, soap, groovy, soapui

I am currently using SOAPUI (Free Version).

I am looking to automate the tests so a value is place in each test, without having to manually enter them.

(At a Basic Level) Example

The test web service I am using is  http://www.webservicex.net/mortgage.asmx?WSDL.

http://www.webservicex.net/mortgage.asmx?op=GetMortgagePayment

The service has been set up as SOAP, a test suite has been built and a SOAP request test step has been assigned.

Out of the box, you can enter data manually in to the test step. However I am wanting too achieve three things using the free addition.

1. Add a randomized value to the test, so that a value of between is inserted each time the test is run. I am aware you can use Groovy but I am unsure whether the Groovy script needs to be added as a test step or as the set up script tab
2. Pull a list of data from a `.csv` or similar so the test continues to run through all data.
3. Repeat step 2 but set the assertions for each piece of test data to state whether the response should be valid or not.

If you could help it would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: It can be achieved by writing `groovy script`. if not already, you can have a look at [this](https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/).

Comment: Thanks I understand we can use Groovy, however i can not find anyone who has actually managed to successfully do this since 2012. Accept on SOAPUI Pro, which has an inbuilt feature. I am trying to repeat the scenario in 2016 and cannot get it work

Comment: Please show what you have done? where do you think the problem is ? Any stacktrace?